# nginx lua not able to set headers before rewrite

Tags: redirect, nginx, lua, openresty

I have a set of ip address in my redis server to be blocked. Now when a client makes a request,

1. the request must be intercepted by nginx
2. check if the remote_addr belongs to the blocked ip
3. add a header if the ip is blocked
4. then redirect to the actual ip address with the request_uri.

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    lua_shared_dict ip_status 1m;

    server {
        listen       9080;
        server_name  localhost;
        location ~ .* {
            rewrite_by_lua_file src/ip_check.lua;
        }
    }
}
```

src/ip_check.lua

```
-- redis configuration
local redis_host                = "127.0.0.1"
local redis_port                = 6379  -- connection timeouts for redis in ms.
local redis_max_idle_timeout    = 10000
local redis_pool_size           = 2     --  don't set this too high!
local redis_timeout             = 200

-- check a set with this key for blacklist entries
local redis_key         = ngx.var.remote_addr
local ip_status         = ngx.shared.ip_status
local status_unblocked  = "0"
local status_blocked    = "1"
-- cache lookups for this many seconds
local cache_ttl         = 1800

local redirect_host             = "http://192.168.12.103:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorld1"
local header_ip_status_key      = "Ip-Status"
-- value of the header to be sent when the client ip address is blocked
local header_ip_status_value    = "block"
local add_header                = status_unblocked

-- lookup the value in the cache
local cache_result = ip_status:get(redis_key)
if cache_result then
  if cache_result == status_blocked then
    add_header = status_blocked
  end
else
  -- lookup against redis
  local resty = require "resty.redis"
  local redis = resty:new()
  redis:set_timeout(redis_timeout)

  local connected, err = redis:connect(redis_host, redis_port)
  if not connected then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "ip_check: could not connect to redis @"..redis_host..":"..redis_port.." - "..err)
  else
    ngx.log(ngx.ALERT, "ip_check: found connect to redis @"..redis_host..":"..redis_port.." - successful")

    local result, err = redis:get(redis_key)
    if not result then
      ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "ip_check: lookup failed for "..ngx.var.remote_addr.." - "..err)
    else
      if result == status_blocked then
        add_header = status_blocked
      end

      -- cache the result from redis
      ip_status:set(ip, add_header, cache_ttl)
    end

    redis:set_keepalive(redis_max_idle_timeout, redis_pool_size)
  end
end

ngx.log(ngx.ALERT, "ip_check: "..header_ip_status_key.." of "..ngx.var.remote_addr.." is "..add_header)
if add_header == status_blocked then
    ngx.header[header_ip_status_key] = header_ip_status_value
    ngx.req.set_header(header_ip_status_key, header_ip_status_value)
end

ngx.redirect(redirect_host..ngx.var.request_uri)
```

For testing purpose, i added 127.0.0.1 key to redis with value 1. So, the redirect uri should be hit with the additional header. The problem i'm facing is no matter what i use ngx.header or ngx.req.set_header the **Ip-Status** header is not sent to the redirect request and the end api does not recieve it.

For example if i hit http://localhost:9080/hello in the browser,

Request headers

```
Host:"localhost:9080"
User-Agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
Accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
Accept-Language:"en-US,en;q=0.5"
Accept-Encoding:"gzip, deflate"
Connection:"keep-alive"
```

Response headers

```
Connection:"keep-alive"
Content-Length:"166"
Content-Type:"text/html"
Date:"Thu, 05 May 2016 08:06:33 GMT"
Location:"http://192.168.12.103:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorld1/hello"
Server:"openresty/1.9.7.2"
ip-status:"block"
```

The redirected uri is http://localhost:9080/hello,

Request headers

```
Host:"192.168.12.103:8080"
User-Agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
Accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
Accept-Language:"en-US,en;q=0.5"
Accept-Encoding:"gzip, deflate"
Cookie:"JSESSIONID=4834843FE0E76170E429028E096A66E5"
Connection:"keep-alive"
```

Response headers

```
Content-Language:"en-US"
Content-Length:"166"
Content-Type:"text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Date:"Thu, 05 May 2016 08:06:33 GMT"
Server:"Apache-Coyote/1.1"
```

I'm able to see **Ip-Status** header in response headers of the original request but not in the request headers of the redirected uri. Any help as to how to send header to the redirected uri will be very helpful.

I'm new to nginx and lua. Asking because i couldn't find any corresponding questions apologies if the question is already asked.

Comment: Requests are sent by browser. You have no control on headers it will send.

Comment: @AlexeyTen thanks for the suggestion. That helped in understanding what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the browser that is redirecting to the redirected uri and nginx do not have control on the headers. So, i removed

```
ngx.redirect(redirect_host..ngx.var.request_uri)
```

from the src/ip_check.lua and changed nginx.conf to make a proxy call and i was able to observe that the api was able to receive the additional header.

Modified nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    lua_shared_dict ip_status 1m;

    server {
        listen       9080;
        server_name  localhost;
        location ~ .* {
            set $backend_host   "http://192.168.12.103:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorld1";
            access_by_lua_file src/ip_check.lua;
            proxy_pass $backend_host$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

This modified nginx.conf will make a request to **$backend_host$request_uri** and browser will not have any knowledge of the redirections made. Hence, the headers set by ngx.req.set_header will be sent when making the proxy call. So,

```
ngx.header[header_ip_status_key] = header_ip_status_value
```

can also be removed from src/ip_check.lua.